# Adding Soft and Hard Deadlines to the Linux Scheduler

Tags: c, kernel, scheduler, deadlines

I am trying to create two new system calls for the Kernel, to set and get deadlines.

I know the general concept, but I am struggling as to what the `.c` files will look like.

Could anyone give me some examples as to how, given a process's pid, give it a soft/hard deadline.

Also, if possible I'd like to know how I can examine if a process is child of another process or not.

Comment: Do you know how to add and test new syscalls on Linux? What about the code is confusing? What have you tried so far? What do you mean by deadline, let alone a soft vs hard deadline? Why do you want to create new syscalls for this? The last part about checking if a process is a child of another is answerable as is, but the rest requires more information.

Comment: The reason i m doing this is to modify the Linux Scheduler and set deadlines for each process. So how do i check if a process is a child of another process ?

Comment: Ah, then that's out of my wheelhouse, sorry :)